# ActiveRecord: Select a record only if it has expired and a new one isn't available

Tags: mysql, activerecord

Currently, I'm working on a Signup model with ActiveRecord which has the following attributes:

- issue_date
- expiration_date
- signup_status
- student_id

And what I'm trying to achieve is to show 1 signup per student (another model: a student has many signups) only if the latest student's signup has expired and a new one isn't available.

To make things a little bit clearer, let's say I have 2 signups from two different students issued on September 23rd, 2014 and are now expired. And today I decided to generate a new issue for one of the students, so now we have one Student with an active Signup and another one with an expired Signup. The Student with the active Signup should be filtered and should not show up, while the Student with the expired Signup should appear as long as a new Signup isn't generated for him.

The closest I've got to achieve my goal was with the following AR query with no success:

```
@expired_signups = Signup.where(
signup_status: 'Expired signup').group(:student_id).having(
"MAX(expiration_date) >= #{Date.today}").order(student_id: :desc)
```

The query shows up the latest expired signup regardless of whether the Student has an active Signup or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can share more detail? It seems to me that an `Expired Signup` would always have an `expiration_date >= Date.today` so that is perhaps not needed. What is the query currently returning?

Comment: @BenHawker As in right now, the query returns the latest signup created, whether it's expired or not.